# Image uploading doesn't work

Tags: php, html

So guys.. I want to upload an image to a certain folder name "uploads" and insert the name of that image on database, the problem is that he isn't uploading the image..

So i have this basic **HTML** code:

```html
<form action="newimage.php" method="POST">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic">
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

And this is my **PHP** page

```html
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "homepage");
 
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  $name = "somethinghere";

  #do upload
  $target_dir = "uploads";
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
  $newfilename = $target_dir . '/Foto-' . $name . '.' . end($temp);

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $newfilename) ) {
    $productimage = 'Foto-' . $name . '.' . end($temp);
  }
  else
  {
    $productimage = '';
  }


  $sql = "INSERT INTO galeria_front (image_name) VALUES ('$productimage')";

  if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      header("Location: galery.php");
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
  }

  $mysqli->close();
?>
```

As you can see i have a conection which works, and tried to insert the productimage into the database table but for some reason , it's entering the else{} and making my productimage empty on the database which means the above upload isn't working.

P.S(Pardon me for any bad english)

Comment: I forgot to mention, i verified the permissions and folders path, everything is ok

Comment: `<form action="newimage.php" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Anything wrong with that? I tried that already , didint work anyway

Comment: add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in your <form > tag

Comment: without an `enctype` on your form, the file will never get uploaded. You can check `$_FILES['pic']['error']` on the server side to find out any problems with the upload.

Comment: also your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Use parameterised queries instead. Someone could potentially name the file `';DROP TABLE galeria_front;--.jpg` or something, and mess up your data. It's even worse because you're logging in as root which has privileges to do anything it likes. Create a new login for your app which only has access to the things it actually needs in order to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding these

```
     <form action="newimage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    </form
```

Alter your script into this

```
    <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
     // Check file size
     if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
     }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
     "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
     }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
   {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
    uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @MickaelGonçalves you still need it, even if it doesn't entirely solve the problem, it's one step on the road.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form action="/process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```